# Diffusing a cuboid

Tags: python, numpy

I have some cuboid data stored in numpy arrays, of shape say (512, 512, 512).

I need to diffuse the values within the array, to the mean of the first order neighbors of each point in the cuboid. So the result should be an array with the same shape (512, 512, 512).

Comment: What approach did you try?

Comment: I was thinking of using convolution of some kind, but did not come up how to avoid using slow for loops yet. Also using something like nearest neighbors is possible, but only if I most values of the volume are filtered to reduce the number of data points, which is  undesirable

Comment: Try a GPU-accelerated deep learning framework like TensorFlow or PyTorch.

Comment: That might do, I was thinking of how to apply 'regular 2D' convolutions to the problem, just saw that pytorch has 3D convolutions, which might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Susmit in the comments, convolutions can be used.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

def dilute(data, order=1):
    size = 1 + order * 2

    weights = torch.ones((1, 1, size, size, size)) / (size ** 3)
    weights = weights.to(torch.float32)

    data = np.pad(data, order, mode='reflect')
    data = torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32)
    data = data.view((1, 1, *data.shape))

    data = F.conv3d(data, weights, stride=1)
    return data
```